# Google Analytics API for dateRange of previous month

Tags: ssis, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, cozyroc

We are reading the Google Analytics data using Cozyroc REST Source component in SSIS package. While reading the data, I can add the dateRange startDate and endDate in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. Instead of adding static values, I wanted to read the data for 1st date to last date of previous month. As I see, there is nthdayago field. But how I can achieve the dateRange of previous month dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

The only relative dates expressions are `today`, `yesterday` or `NdaysAgo`, so you have to create a custom formula in your system to go back to the length of the previous month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can take variables:

```
@LastMonth = dateadd("m",-1,getdate())
@LastMonthDay1 = (DT_DATE) ( (DT_WSTR,2)Month(@LastMonth) + "/1/"  + (DT_WSTR,4) year(@LastMonth)) 
@LastMonthLastDay = dateadd("d",-1,dateadd("m",1,@LastMonthDay1))
```

Comment: I thought of same, but we are using Cozyroc component in SSIS package and we can pass those SSIS variables to the third-party component.

Comment: Why use that tool then? I almost exclusively use c# script task / component and WebClient